# Why does Collections.max() not return actual max value for a Collection of String?

Tags: java, collections, compare

```
ArrayList<String> dirNo = new ArrayList<String>();

dirNo.add("1");
dirNo.add("2");
dirNo.add("3");
dirNo.add("4");
dirNo.add("5");
dirNo.add("6");
dirNo.add("7");
dirNo.add("8");
dirNo.add("9");
dirNo.add("10");
dirNo.add("11");

System.out.println("max : " + Integer.parseInt(Collections.max(dirNo)));
```

After executing above code, print **9** as output.

But actually max value should be **11**.

Why am I getting **9** as max ?

Comment: You're doing String comparison. That's something completely different than integer comparison. Change your code to use Integer and everything should work like a charm.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Since your elements are strings, `Collections.max()` is returning the value that's the largest [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

If you wish to compare the strings numerically, you need to use the two-argument version of [`Collections.max()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator%29) and supply an appropriate comparator:

```
    ArrayList<String> dirNo = new ArrayList<String>();

    dirNo.add("1");
    dirNo.add("2");
    dirNo.add("3");
    dirNo.add("4");
    dirNo.add("5");
    dirNo.add("6");
    dirNo.add("7");
    dirNo.add("8");
    dirNo.add("9");
    dirNo.add("10");
    dirNo.add("11");

    Comparator<String> cmp = new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(o1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2));
        }
    };
    System.out.println("max : " + Collections.max(dirNo, cmp));
```

Comment: For me it works like this (get max integer from array of number strings): 
`Arrays.stream( myStringnumberArray ).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).max().orElse(-1);`

Answer (score 1):

You are using a String collection! String comparison is completely different from number comparsion.

String value `"2" > "11"` because `'2' > '1'` (first character difference)

Answer (score 0):

Change String to Integer

```
ArrayList<Integer> dirNo = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

this should work fine

```
String[] allLongestStrings(String[] inputArray) {
    ArrayList<String> newArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayIndex = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> longestString = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0; i < inputArray.length;i++){
        newArray.add(inputArray[i]);
        arrayIndex.add(inputArray[i].length());
    }

    int maximumVal = Collections.max(arrayIndex);

    for(int j=0; j < newArray.size();j++){
        if(newArray.get(j).length() >= maximumVal){
            longestString.add(newArray.get(j));
        }    
    }   

    String[] stringArray = longestString.toArray(new 
    String[longestString.size()]);
    return stringArray;
```

}