# Android - Do I need to sort a collection for min and max?

Tags: android, sorting, collections, max, min

I came here (SO) a few days ago to research how to get the min and max from a collection in Android and found a solution to the effect of the following (sorry haven't got a link to the actual answer I used):

```
Max = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Max);
Collections.sort(list);
Max.setText(String.format("%.2f", Collections.max(list)));
```

My question is do I actually need to sort the list before pulling the min/max value? I have tried running the code without sorting the list and it seems to work OK. I am just worried because the answer I used definitely sorted the list first so I assume there must be a reason, I just don't know what it is!

Comment: Thanks all; it is a list of doubles so they should sort 'properly'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition @BobbyDigital's answer who corectly points out the th method iterates over the complete list, I would just like to mention that the result of using the `max` function might depend on the type of the list elements. If you see the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29) , it says that

> Returns the maximum element of the given collection, according to the natural ordering of its elements.

If you see [Why does Collections.max() not return actual max value for a Collection of String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403183/collections-max-not-return-actual-max-value) question, the person used a list of `Strings`. On extracting max using the abve number he did not get the max number as it was returning the value that's the largest [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). So, just to mention his code:

```
ArrayList<String> dirNo = new ArrayList<String>();

dirNo.add("1");
dirNo.add("2");
dirNo.add("3");
dirNo.add("4");
dirNo.add("5");
dirNo.add("6");
dirNo.add("7");
dirNo.add("8");
dirNo.add("9");
dirNo.add("10");
dirNo.add("11");

System.out.println("max : " + Integer.parseInt(Collections.max(dirNo))
        + "");
```

The above code gave `9` as the answer. So be careful while using it. You mgiht want to convert everything to `Integer` etc based on your needs.

P.S: The example is from the question mentioned and the answer is inspired from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15403208/1306419) answer by [NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367273/npe) on same question.

Comment: But wouldn't sorting it give the same results. I understood the question to be does sorting prior matter.

Comment: You are right. His question was that does sorting prior to using max matter( and you answered that already :) ) .I mentioned this seeing the overall intention of what the person is trying to do. Since he wants to get the max from the list, I just though it would be good thing to keep at the back of mind ( the result might not be the one which he expected).

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't have to be sorted. The method iterates over the entire collection.
[See the Java docs for the method!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max)

Comment: Just to add a little to Bobby's answer, you don't have to sort, no, but what max and min mean depends on the types in your collection. See the specific "max" method for instance: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection) (uses the *natural* order, if you want some other order supply a Comparator [next method down]).